# Android: How to Upload Images

Tags: android, image-uploading

I am working on a SugarCRM client. In this App I take images from camera. I have to save this image in the cache and upload it on live server. Please some-one guide me through this. How can I convert Bitmap image into 'data' and upload it through JSON Calls.